# Read a character string containing a star character

Tags: fortran

I want to read this line by Fortran 77 :

```
 CH2*                3.667979E-19
```

and I have written this code to read this line

```
PROGRAM READCH2
CHARACTER(10) :: SPEC
REAL(8) :: X
open(1,FILE='CH2.TXT')
  READ(1,*)SPEC,X
CLOSE(1)
PRINT*,SPEC,X
PAUSE
END PROGRAM READCH2
```

but the code could not read `CH2*` because it contains a star. 
How could I read `CH2*`?

Comment: What does ` the code could not read` mean? Was anything read? What? Or some error message? Which?

Comment: As repeated many many times here, you should use explicit format.